# Getting rid of a nested for loop to improve performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, grouping

I have a function thats supposed to be merge two objects together based on certain conditions. the vitalsArray is an array of objects that are unsorted that may or may not have corresponding values (i.e systolic to diastolic and vice versa). Basically if certain conditions are met that would mean that the systolic object and the diastolic object are one BP vital and need to be merged.

My question is is there a better way of doing this than a nested forEach loop?

```
const mergeBloodPressures = (vitalsArray) => {
  let ids = []
  let finalArray = []
  vitalsArray.forEach((tmpBP) => {
    vitalsArray.forEach((bp) => {
      let matchDate = moment(bp.takenOn).isSame(
        moment(tmpBP.takenOn),
        "minute"
      )
      if (
        matchDate &&
        bp.vitalType.name != tmpBP.vitalType.name &&
        !ids.includes(bp.id) &&
        !ids.includes(tmpBP.id)
      ) {
        let temp = {}
        if (bp.vitalType.name == "diastolic blood pressure") {
          temp.diastolic = bp
          temp.systolic = tmpBP
        } else {
          temp.diastolic = tmpBP
          temp.systolic = bp
        }
        ids.push(bp.id)
        finalArray.push(temp)
      }
    })
  })
  return finalArray
}
```

Sample Input:

```
[
{
    "patient_id": 716,
    "vital_type_id": 2,
    "value": "78",
    "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
    "vitalType": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "diastolic_blood_pressure",
        "units": "mmHg",
        "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00"
    },
    "id": 9101,
},
{
    "patient_id": 716,
    "vital_type_id": 1,
    "value": "129",
    "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
    "vital_type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "systolic_blood_pressure",
        "units": "mmHg",
        "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00"
    },
    "id": 9102,
}
]
```

Sample Output:

```
[
{
    "diastolic": {
        "patient_id": 716,
        "vital_type_id": 2,
        "value": "78",
        "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
        "vitalType": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "diastolic_blood_pressure",
            "units": "mmHg",
            "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00"
        },
        "id": 9101,
    },
    "systolic": {
        "patient_id": 716,
        "vital_type_id": 1,
        "value": "129",
        "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
        "vitalType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "systolic_blood_pressure",
            "units": "mmHg",
            "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00"
        },
        "id": 9102
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Looks like a simple 'group-by' would probably solve your problem, but you'll need to post a sample of your input and expected output.

Comment: Unlikely but for that edgecase I added an ids array to check in the if loop if that bp is there

Comment: @pilchard Added the input and outputs, only added a few since the vitalsArray is in the thousands

Comment: My first thought is the same as mentioned by pilchard. Call it group-by or sort your input array by patient id. That way you can cancel the inner loop when the patient id changes - that should give you some performance if there are multiple patiens. Second thought is the way you retrieve the data. If you get them by an ajax request, make sure the server is able to compress the data to reduce the download size. last thought is your id array. keep the id array sorted and instead of `include` use binary-search to reduce the id lookup time

Comment: instead of a sorted array and binarysearch you could try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set that would be part of javascript (depends on the browsers you need to support) and should have a better performance than keeping an array sorted and using binarysearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input only shows a single patient on a single date but here is an example  that extrapolates from that a little to provide a result that is grouped by `patient_id` and then further grouped by `taken_on` within that.

The result is of the following shape:

```
[
  {
    "patient_id": 1,
    "vitals": [
      {
        "diastolic": {
          taken_on: 1,
          //...
        },
        "systolic": {
          taken_on: 1,
          //...
        }
      },
      {
        "diastolic": {
          taken_on: 2,
          //...
        },
        "systolic": {
          taken_on: 2,
          //...
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "patient_id": 2,
    "vitals": [
      {
        "diastolic": {
          taken_on: 1,
          //...
        },
        "systolic": {
          taken_on: 1,
          //...
        }
      },
      //...
    ]
  }
]
```

To achieve this the example below iterates each element using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop then retrieves or creates the a `patient_id` property using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). It then further retrieves or initializes an object to group into based on `taken_on`. Finally the result is created by taking the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the grouped object and mapping over it in order to also convert each `taken_on` object to a an array of values.

```js
const input = [{ "patient_id": 716, "vital_type_id": 2, "value": "78", "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00", "vitalType": { "id": 2, "name": "diastolic_blood_pressure", "units": "mmHg", "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00", "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00" }, "id": 9101, }, { "patient_id": 716, "vital_type_id": 1, "value": "129", "taken_on": "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00", "vital_type": { "id": 1, "name": "systolic_blood_pressure", "units": "mmHg", "created_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00", "updated_at": "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00" }, "id": 9102, }];

const vitalTypesById = {
  1: 'systolic',
  2: 'diastolic'
};

const groupedByPatient = {};
for (const o of input) {
  const takenOn = new Date(o.taken_on).setSeconds(0, 0);

  const patient = (groupedByPatient[o.patient_id] ??= {});
  const patientByDate = (patient[takenOn] ??= {});

  patientByDate[vitalTypesById[o.vital_type_id]] = { ...o };
}

const result = Object.entries(groupedByPatient).map(([patient_id, vitals]) => (
  {
    patient_id,
    vitals: Object.values(vitals)
  }
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. It cut down the load time by half!

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by patientid and takenon.  I would suggest running through the vitals array and stuff it into a dictionary based on vital name.

Conceptually you'd do something like so.

```
var mydictionary[] = {};
for (val in vitalsarray) {
    let key = val.patientId + "." + val.takenOn;
    if (mydictionary[key]) {
        let list = mydictonary[key];
        list.push( val );
    } else {
        let listo = [];
        listo.push( val );
        mydictionary[ key ] = listo;
    }
}
```

The above is sort a pseudo code, but that gets you the patient stuff grouped to together.  If you get a little slicker, you can actually look at the list and have a further dictionary which contains the vitals by type....

Answer (score 0):

The next provided approach utilizes [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) where the reducer function aggregates/merges related(same) blood pressure data, based on a unique key which itself is a concatenation of a patient's ID (`patient_id`) and the date/timestamp of measurement (`taken_on`).

The result is a key based index/map/object of merged related blood pressure data-items (`blood pressure data`). Passing such an object to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an array of said data items.

```js
function aggregateRelatedBloodPressureData(index, dataItem) {
  const { patient_id, taken_on, vital_type } = dataItem;

  const relatedDataKey = `${ patient_id }_${ taken_on }`;
  const pressureType = vital_type.name.split('_')[0] ?? vital_type.name;

  Object
    .assign(
      index[relatedDataKey] ??= {},
      { [pressureType]: dataItem },
    );
  return index;
}

const sampleDate = [{
  patient_id: 716,
  vital_type_id: 2,
  value: "78",
  taken_on: "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
  vital_type: {
    id: 2,
    name: "diastolic_blood_pressure",
    units: "mmHg",
    created_at: "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00",
    updated_at: "2022-06-22T14:40:43.746-05:00",
  },
  id: 9101,
}, {
  patient_id: 716,
  vital_type_id: 1,
  value: "129",
  taken_on: "2022-06-22T14:49:48.948-05:00",
  vital_type: {
    id: 1,
    name: "systolic_blood_pressure",
    units: "mmHg",
    created_at: "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00",
    updated_at: "2022-06-22T14:40:43.740-05:00",
  },
  id: 9102,
}];

const aggregatedBloodPressureIndex = sampleDate
  .reduce(aggregateRelatedBloodPressureData, {});

const aggregatedBloodPressureList = Object
  .values(aggregatedBloodPressureIndex);

console.log({
  aggregatedBloodPressureIndex,
  aggregatedBloodPressureList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```